# configure ci_secrets for Jenkins ci

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, travis-ci, gitlab-ci, git-secret

ci_secrets is (https://github.com/pmarlow/ci_secrets) is a repo secret scanning tool which can easily be integrated with Travis and Gitlab ci without a need for a persistent server.
Configuring this into the Jenkins pipeline is a bit tricky though as Jenkins does not support the environment variables like

```
"TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE" and/or
```

which is required to determine the latest-scanned commit from the first commit in the range.

is there a way to implement this in a Jenkins pipeline?

for example:

```
script:
   - export COMMIT_RANGE=${TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE:-"000000000000000000000000000000000000"}
   - export LAST_COMMIT=${COMMIT_RANGE%%.*}
   - ci_secrets --since $LAST_COMMIT --includeMergeCommit --log INFO
```